# How do I hotcopy a SVN Repository to an existing location?

Tags: svn, backup, batch-file, repository

I am trying to automatically backup my SVN Repository.  This is in a batch file I wrote:

```
svnadmin hotcopy C:/myRepository G:/myRepositoryBackup --clean-logs
```

It works great the first time.  However, each time after that, I get this error:

```
svnadmin: 'G:/myRepositoryBackup' exists and is non-empty
```

How do I have it overwrite my old data, or copy incrementally?

I know I can just use `svnadmin dump` but I want the smaller `hotcopy` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `svnadmin dump repo --incremental`.

You can find more repository backup info here:

[SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/) -> [Chapter 5. Repository Administration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05.html) -> [Repository Backup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.6)

Answer (score 2):

What I do for SVN backups is use `svnadmin dump` and then compress the output with 7-Zip. For my repository, this ends up being smaller than the `hotcopy`. Then I have a single file every day that contains the entire repository backup. Furthermore, the `dump` output is more robust in the face of future repository format changes (the `hotcopy` output can only be restored to exactly the same SVN version).

Comment: hotcopy 996MB ... dump 2.93GB ... erm